# How to expand and collapse the table rows in plain react js. Show only one row if the description of the row is multiple and show the expand button

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am working on the table content which has 5 rows . few rows content description is same so I need to show only one row in this case and give expan button. when expand button is clicked it should show all the rows which has the same associated description. I am pasting the screenshot which I got as output .

In the above screenshot I've got the "-" button for all the rows which has same description. but I need only one "-"(collapse) button for "paytm" and one "-"button for "Paypal". and when they are clicked only one paytm, PayPal should be displayed.

```
     let rows = [
          {
            id: { value: '' },
            description: { value: 'Paytm' },       
            DueDate: { value: '04/03/2020' },  
          },
          {
            id: { value: '' },
            description: { value: 'paypal' }, 
            DueDate: { value: '04/04/2021' }
          },
          {
            id: { value: '' },
            description: { value: 'paypal' }, 
            DueDate: { value: '04/03/2020' }
          },
          {
            id: { value: '' },
            description: { value: 'Paytm' },
            DueDate: { value: '04/03/2021' }
          },
          {
            id: { value: '' },
            description: { value: 'Gpay' }, 
            DueDate: { value: '04/03/2020' }
          },
        ];
```

I am showing the table based on the lasted date and check if there exists any multiple same descriptions and putting them  all in one object.

```
    const descriptionSortedArray = rows.reduce((acc, current) => {
          acc[current.description.value] = [
            ...(acc[current.description.value] || []),
            current,
          ];
          return acc;
        }, {});
    
        console.log(descriptionSortedArray);
```

and transforming the object based on latest date

```
     const transformedRows = Object.keys(descriptionSortedArray).reduce(
          (acc, current) => {
            acc[current] = sortRowsByDate(descriptionSortedArray[current]);
            return acc;
          },
          {}
        );
        // console.log(Object.keys(descriptionSortedArray));
        console.log({ transformedRows });
```

and getting the key values for them by using object.keys and mapping over them.

```
    x.[paytm:[], Gpay:[], PayPal :[]];
```

based on the inner array key length  I am showing button (expand and collapse)if
x[paytm]>1 ?show button: without button

code is below

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import './style.css';
    
    export default class App extends React.Component {
      render() {
        let rows = [
          {
            id: { value: '' },
            description: { value: 'Paytm' },       
            DueDate: { value: '04/03/2020' },  
          },
          {
            id: { value: '' },
            description: { value: 'paypal' }, 
            DueDate: { value: '04/04/2021' }
          },
          {
            id: { value: '' },
            description: { value: 'paypal' }, 
            DueDate: { value: '04/03/2020' }
          },
          {
            id: { value: '' },
            description: { value: 'Paytm' },
            DueDate: { value: '04/03/2021' }
          },
          {
            id: { value: '' },
            description: { value: 'Gpay' }, 
            DueDate: { value: '04/03/2020' }
          },
        ];
    
        const descriptionSortedArray = rows.reduce((acc, current) => {
          acc[current.description.value] = [
            ...(acc[current.description.value] || []),
            current,
          ];
          return acc;
        }, {});
    
        console.log(descriptionSortedArray);
    
        const sortRowsByDate = (rows) =>
          rows.sort(
            (a, b) => new Date(b.DueDate.value) - new Date(a.DueDate.value)
          );
    
        const transformedRows = Object.keys(descriptionSortedArray).reduce(
          (acc, current) => {
            acc[current] = sortRowsByDate(descriptionSortedArray[current]);
            return acc;
          },
          {}
        );
        // console.log(Object.keys(descriptionSortedArray));
        console.log({ transformedRows });
        
    
        return (
          <div>
            <table>
              <tr>
                <th>id</th>
                <th>description</th>
                <th>duedate</th>
                <th></th>
               
              </tr>
              {Object.keys(transformedRows).map((rowKey) => {
                // console.log("rowKey===", rowKey)
                //   console.log(transformedRows[rowKey])
                return (
                  <tbody>
                    {transformedRows[rowKey].length > 1
                      ? transformedRows[rowKey].map((obj) => (
                          <tr>
                            <td>{obj.id.value}</td>
                            <td>{obj.description.value}</td>  
                            <td>{obj.DueDate.value}</td>
                            <td>{<button>-</button>}</td>
                                                  </tr>
                        ))
                      : transformedRows[rowKey].map((obj) => (
                          <tr>
                            <td>{obj.id.value}</td>
                            <td>{obj.description.value}</td> 
                            <td>{obj.DueDate.value}</td>
                            <td></td>
                          </tr>
                        ))}
                  </tbody>
                );
              })}
            </table>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

Please help in this. I need to show only one collapse button for the rows having same description(paytm is repeated show them only in one row give "expand" and "collapse" button). when even button is clicked it should be toggled. Please help

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-6dt9gp?file=src%2FApp.js I've implemented an exapmle here, if it solves your problem let me to post it as answer.

Comment: @Saeed Shamloo it works for me. It is appreciated if you can help me with the need of 
 both paytm and paypal comes under same group so there should not be any   "border" between them when expanded.

Comment: I didn't understand exactly what you mean, but I made some changes in the example. please check it out.

Comment: thanks for trying, but still when I clicked on expand  paytm, paypal rows  also are loading.

previous one was fine. It was almost full filling my requirement . I will try for border collapse. Please upload previous answer.

Comment: I reverted to previous one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can keep another field called visible along with your data array and toggle its value when clicked on the button.

1. Define a state to store the `transformedRows`

```
  state = {
    transformedRows: {}
  };
```

2. Do the transformation like below in `componentDidMount`.

```
  componentDidMount = () => {
    const descriptionSortedArray = rows.reduce((acc, current) => {
      acc[current.description.value] = {
        ...acc[current.description.value],
        data: [...(acc[current.description.value]?.["data"] ?? []), current],
        visible: false
      };
      return acc;
    }, {});

    const sortRowsByDate = (rows) =>
      rows.sort(
        (a, b) => new Date(b.DueDate.value) - new Date(a.DueDate.value.data)
      );

    const transformedRows = Object.keys(descriptionSortedArray).reduce(
      (acc, current) => {
        acc[current] = {
          ...descriptionSortedArray[current],
          data: sortRowsByDate(descriptionSortedArray[current]["data"])
        };
        return acc;
      },
      {}
    );
    this.setState({ transformedRows });
  };
```

3. Toggle the visible state when clicking on the button.

```
  handleToggle = (entry, visibility) => {
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      return {
        ...prevState,
        transformedRows: Object.fromEntries(
          Object.entries(prevState.transformedRows).map(([key, value]) => {
            if (key === entry) {
              return [key, { ...value, visible: visibility }];
            } else {
              return [key, value];
            }
          })
        )
      };
    });
  };
```

4. Render rows as below.

```
<tbody>
    {Object.entries(transformedRows).map(([key, { data, visible }]) => {
        if (data.length > 1) {
            return data.map((item, index) => (
                <tr>
                    {(index === 0 || (index >= 1 && visible)) && (
                        <>
                            <td>{item.id.value}</td>
                            <td>{item.description.value}</td>
                            <td>{item.DueDate.value}</td>
                        </>
                    )}
                    {index === 0 && (
                        <td>
                            {
                                <button
                                    onClick={() => {
                                        this.handleToggle(key, !visible);
                                    }}
                                >
                                    toggle
                                </button>
                            }
                        </td>
                    )}
                </tr>
            ));
        } else {
            return data.map(item => (
                <tr>
                    <td>{item.id.value}</td>
                    <td>{item.description.value}</td>
                    <td>{item.DueDate.value}</td>
                </tr>
            ));
        }
    })}
</tbody>
```

[image: Edit focused-dew-zpv76]

Comment: @Sathish, check this out !!

Answer (score 1):

[image]

[image]

Create an accordion component as follow:

[React accordion](https://codepen.io/AdamMorsi/pen/ZZJPoj)

Then use it as follow:

```
return (
    <div>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>id</th>
                    <th>description</th>
                    <th>duedate</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            {Object.keys(transformedRows).map((rowKey) => {
                // console.log("rowKey===", rowKey)
                //   console.log(transformedRows[rowKey])
                console.log(rowKey);
                return (
                    <tbody key={rowKey}>
                        {transformedRows[rowKey].length > 1 ? (
                            <tr>
                                <td colSpan="4">
                                    <Accordion label={rowKey}>
                                        {transformedRows[rowKey].map((obj) => (
                                            <div key={obj.id.value}>
                                                <span>{obj.id.value}</span>
                                                <span>{obj.description.value}</span>
                                                <span>{obj.DueDate.value}</span>
                                                <span>{<button>-</button>}</span>
                                            </div>
                                        ))}
                                    </Accordion>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        ) : (
                            transformedRows[rowKey].map((obj) => (
                                <tr key={obj.id.value}>
                                    <td>{obj.id.value}</td>
                                    <td>{obj.description.value}</td>
                                    <td>{obj.DueDate.value}</td>
                                    <td></td>
                                </tr>
                            ))
                        )}
                    </tbody>
                );
            })}
        </table>
    </div>
);
```

Full code:

```
let rows = [
    {
        id: { value: '1' },
        description: { value: 'Paytm' },
        DueDate: { value: '04/03/2020' },
    },
    {
        id: { value: '2' },
        description: { value: 'paypal' },
        DueDate: { value: '04/04/2021' },
    },
    {
        id: { value: '3' },
        description: { value: 'paypal' },
        DueDate: { value: '04/03/2020' },
    },
    {
        id: { value: '4' },
        description: { value: 'Paytm' },
        DueDate: { value: '04/03/2021' },
    },
    {
        id: { value: '5' },
        description: { value: 'Gpay' },
        DueDate: { value: '04/03/2020' },
    },
];

const descriptionSortedArray = rows.reduce((acc, current) => {
    acc[current.description.value] = [...(acc[current.description.value] || []), current];
    return acc;
}, {});

console.log(descriptionSortedArray);

const sortRowsByDate = (rows) =>
    rows.sort((a, b) => new Date(b.DueDate.value) - new Date(a.DueDate.value));

const transformedRows = Object.keys(descriptionSortedArray).reduce((acc, current) => {
    acc[current] = sortRowsByDate(descriptionSortedArray[current]);
    return acc;
}, {});

return (
    <div>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>id</th>
                    <th>description</th>
                    <th>duedate</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            {Object.keys(transformedRows).map((rowKey) => {
                // console.log("rowKey===", rowKey)
                //   console.log(transformedRows[rowKey])
                console.log(rowKey);
                return (
                    <tbody key={rowKey}>
                        {transformedRows[rowKey].length > 1 ? (
                            <tr>
                                <td colSpan="4">
                                    <Accordion label={rowKey}>
                                        {transformedRows[rowKey].map((obj) => (
                                            <div key={obj.id.value}>
                                                <span>{obj.id.value}</span>
                                                <span>{obj.description.value}</span>
                                                <span>{obj.DueDate.value}</span>
                                                <span>{<button>-</button>}</span>
                                            </div>
                                        ))}
                                    </Accordion>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        ) : (
                            transformedRows[rowKey].map((obj) => (
                                <tr key={obj.id.value}>
                                    <td>{obj.id.value}</td>
                                    <td>{obj.description.value}</td>
                                    <td>{obj.DueDate.value}</td>
                                    <td></td>
                                </tr>
                            ))
                        )}
                    </tbody>
                );
            })}
        </table>
    </div>
);
```